# How can I search for reopened issues with the GitHub API?

Tags: github-api

I need to see the trend of reopened issues in GitHub. How can I search for a list of reopened issues using the API?

I tried `is:issue is:reopen`, however it returns all issues in open state, even those that were never closed and reopened.

I pull the GitHub data from a Google sheet form with:

```
  var baseURL = "https://api.github.com/";
  var query = "search/issues?q=repo:<my_repo_name_here>+is:issue+label:kind/bug+is:reopened+created:"
  var api = baseURL + query + startDate + ".." + endDate;
```

where `startDate` and `endDate` are taken from a cell value.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than adding additional information in comments.

Comment: github site? github api?

Comment: I updated the question to be more specific. So I and using the GitHub API

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this using query parameters alone, but you can do this using Github's "[List repository issues](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/issues?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-repository-issues)" API.

You'll want to make the call and check for "state_reason" in the response. So your code would look like:

```
 var baseURL = "https://api.github.com";
 var repoOwner = "vuejs";
 var repoName = "core";
 var queryParameters = "state=open&labels=";
 var api = `${baseURL}/repos/${repoOwner}/${repoName}/issues?${queryParameters}`;
```

And assuming you store the JSON as `results` and any given position is `x`, you should be able to check for `results[x].state_reason == "reopened"`.